# Website formatting looks incorrect on Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, width, margin, padding

I'm having problems with a website I'm building. It looks great in all browsers across OS's except *Internet Explorer* (surprise).

Basically the content section of the page is much wider than the header and the footer, despite the width being set correctly (hence working correctly in other browsers). I've tried many things to solve this problem and as of yet can't find a solution.

Does anyone have any ideas?

The website is here: http://www.4dcreative.co.uk

Comment: I can never work out if posts containing a URL such as this are here to leech page rank? I'm probably wrong...

Comment: actually just so you can see the problem but thanks(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using a reset CSS stylesheet, so all of the padding/margin will be different across browsers.

The reset stylesheet basically normalizes everything across all browsers so you start from a blank canvas (rather than having say padding defaults for `li` elements being different in IE than firefox).

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Adding this **before** your own stylesheet should fix it, but might possibly flare up other issues. I would strongly recommend you use it though and fix any other problems that might occur.

Comment: Nice trick. I managed to sort the problem out with conditional CSS, but in future I will probably try this.